# While querying for custom types file in cmis getting error

Tags: cmis, opencmis, dotcmis, cmis-workbench

First I was trying with this code to get all properties of custom type file in my repository. Object Id is of type mcl_engineer. Unable to read custom types file and getting exception.

```
CmisObject objectt = session.getObject(session.createObjectId("09027bd480031032"));
Document document = (Document)objectt;
System.out.println(document.getProperties())
```

While querying also getting exception.

```
SELECT * 
FROM cmis:document 
WHERE cmis:objectId = '09027bd480031032'
```

While querying getting this error

> CMIS Exception: runtime Internal Server Error
>   Error Content: Status code: 500[runtime] Failed to get property info for type: mcl_engineer [E_CANT_INIT_PROPERTY_INFO_CACHE] Cant initialize PropertyInfoCache: mcl_engineer category. You must provide a table owner name qualification on your reference to table mcl_category. [DM_QUERY_E_REG_TABLE_QUAL] You must provide a table owner name qualification on your reference to table mcl_category. (CMIS with REST-Atom binding)

Only getting error for custom type file not for default one. So please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Documentum? Please post the errors that show up in the server's log, thanks!